# How can I stop typescript compiler from aborting because my variable is not in camelCase?

Tags: typescript

I would like to use typescript in my web application, but I don't want it to refuse to compile my code just because it doesn't like the way I name my symbols.

Example: I want to add "_ms" postfix to my variable representing time in milliseconds, but typescript does not allow this:

`error    Identifier 'someDuration_ms' is not in camel case  @typescript-eslint/camelcase`

According to google it should be possible to prevent this error, but nothing I've tried seems to have any effect.

Is there way to prevent these style based errors in general, or camelCase rule specificly?

eslint v6.8.0

My tsconfig.json:

```
   {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "es2015",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": ["error", { "properties": "never" } ],
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's a good rule. I'd listen to it. Your code will be seen as non-idiomatic and have a smell to it.

Comment: Any chance you're using React?
I ended up having to use customize-cra to convince React to use a consistent Babel rule set. https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra

Comment: Using Vue, but I'm getting this error from normal .ts file with no Vue stuff in it.

Comment: Does the project have a separate babel.config.js or babel.rc file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tslint.json` and `tsconfig.json` are two separate configurations. `tslint.json` enforces code style and `tsconfig.json` configures the typescript type checker.

Your error comes from `tslint.json` configuration and you should find your `tslint.json` file and disable the associated rule there instead of in the `tsconfig.json` file.

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/

Comment: I didn't have tslint.json, and adding it didn't help. My application was created with vue-cli and uses Babel, the error says: 
`Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
/path/to/file.ts
  123:13  error    Identifier 'someDuration_ms' is not in camel case  @typescript-eslint/camelcase`
I wonder if there is something special in this setup, as tslint.json appears to have no effect.

Comment: try adding this to your package.json `"eslintConfig": { "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": ["error", { "properties": "never" } ],
  }}`

Comment: "eslintConfig" in package.json had no effect, but adding the rule to .eslintrc.js finally did the trick and error went away, hooray! Maybe cli.vuejs.org is a bit out of date, as file name is .eslintrc.js, not .eslintrc as told there.